# Remove specific index child from parent DOM with removeChild() [Vanilla Javascript]

Tags: javascript, html, dom

i have a table with this basic structure:

```
<thead>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</thead>
<body>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
```

and i want to remove the second child from every "tr" tag, so i would like to do something like this:

```
const rows = document.getElementsByTagName('td')
for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  rows[i].removeChild(target the second child here)
}
```

i'm looking for a solution with pure vanilla javascript (no jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might select the tds you want to remove via a single selector string, it's probably more elegant:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(2)')
  .forEach(td => td.remove());
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>td1</td>
      <td>td2</td>
      <td>td3</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>td1</td>
      <td>td2</td>
      <td>td3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td1</td>
      <td>td2</td>
      <td>td3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>td1</td>
      <td>td2</td>
      <td>td3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If the HTML is valid, the `td`s will necessarily be children of `tr`s regardless, so you don't need to specify that the `td`'s parent is a `tr`.

If you want to target a specific table on the page, rather than every `td` in every table, just put the table identifier in front of the selector string. Eg. if the target table's ID is 'table3', then use the selector string  `'#table3 td:nth-child(2)'` to indicate `td` which are the second child in their parent, which are descendants of the element with ID `table3`.

Answer (score 1):

In VanillaJS you can use `document.querySelectorAll()` and walk over the `2nd td` using `forEach()`

```
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#myTable td:nth-child(2)'), function(td) {
    td.remove();
});
```

---

```js
//$("#myTable td:nth-child(2)").remove()

[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('#myTable td:nth-child(2)'), function(td) {
    td.remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
<thead>
 <tr>
  <td>TD-1</td>
  <td>TD-2</td>
  <td>TD-3</td>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>TD-1</td>
  <td>TD-2</td>
  <td>TD-3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>TD-1</td>
  <td>TD-2</td>
  <td>TD-3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   <td>TD-1</td>
  <td>TD-2</td>
  <td>TD-3</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: That's correct but i was looking for a vanilla javascript solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query selector with `nth-child`.

```
const rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr')
for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  rows[i].removeChild(rows[i].querySelector('td:nth-child(2)'));
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
 </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
  var row = rows[i];
  var td = row.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)');
  row.removeChild(td);
}
</script>
```